# Adding filter to query removes 0 count data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

I need to add filter to my query, but while doing so it removes data with 0 count. Please assist.

```
SELECT tble.dte,
  COUNT(DISTINCT VIN) AS cmt
FROM ATL_GROUNDING_REPORT groundinginfo
RIGHT JOIN
  (SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/03/09 04:00:00 A.M.', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1 + ROWNUM) dte
  FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY ROWNUM                                                                     < 366
  AND TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/03/09 04:00:00 A.M.','YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1 + ROWNUM) <= TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/03/09 03:59:59 P.M.', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss P.M.'))
  ) tble
ON tble.dte = TRUNC(New_Time(groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN,'GMT', 'EST'))
GROUP BY tble.dte
ORDER BY tble.dte DESC;
```

I need to check the condition where groundinginfo.ground_status='Ground' also in this query keeping the data with 0 count as it is.

Comment: Please post the create and insert statements and your desired output.

Comment: I have 2 table specifically Inventory and grounding_info . Each inventory can have multiple grounding info or none. The table structure is as follows.

Inventory
---------              
Inventory_id


Grounding_info
--------------
Info_id
Inventory_id
Grounding_date
I want to get the count of inventories grounded on each date between a given date range. If no inventory grounded on a date , that date should be displayed with count 0.

Comment: Edit your questions and add the create and insert statements. We don't have your tables and data to help you.

Answer (score 1):

If you add a filter as:

```
where groundinginfo.ground_status='Ground'
```

... then you are accidentally turning the outer join into an inner join. This is going to be simpler if you swap the table order and make it a left outer join:

```
SELECT tble.dte,
  COUNT(DISTINCT groundinginfo.VIN) AS cmt
FROM (
  SELECT TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/03/09 04:00:00 A.M.', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1 + ROWNUM) dte
  FROM DUAL
  CONNECT BY ROWNUM < 366
  AND TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/03/09 04:00:00 A.M.','YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss A.M.') - 1 + ROWNUM)
    <= TRUNC(TO_DATE('2015/03/09 03:59:59 P.M.', 'YYYY/MM/DD hh:mi:ss P.M.'))
  ) tble
LEFT JOIN ATL_GROUNDING_REPORT groundinginfo
ON TRUNC(New_Time(groundinginfo.DATE_TURNED_IN,'GMT', 'EST')) = tble.dte
AND groundinginfo.ground_status='Ground'
GROUP BY tble.dte
ORDER BY tble.dte DESC;
```

Notice that the `ground_status` filter is part of the `ON` join condition, and *not* in a `WHERE` clause.